# fetch() not catching custom error message

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, catch-block

I have the following fetch() api but the catch blocks aren't working correctly.  The error message I get is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 undefined
```

but what I'm expecting is:

```
something went wrong null
```

here's the api:

```
const getBtn = document.getElementById('get-btn')
const postBtn = document.getElementById('post-btn')


const sendHttpRequest = (method, url, data) => {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: data ? {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} : {}
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.status)
            if(response.status >= 400 || response == null){
                return response.json()
                    .then(errResData => {
                        const error = new Error('something went wrong')
                        error.data = errResData
                        throw error;
                    })
            }
            return response.json()
    })
}

const getData = () =>{
    sendHttpRequest('GET','http://localhost/async/fetch/data.jsonx')
        .then(responseData => {
            console.log(responseData)
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err,err.data)
        })

}

const sendData = () =>{
    sendHttpRequest('POST','http://localhost/async/fetch/data.phpx',{
        email: 'someemail@gmail.com',
        password: 'compas'
    })
        .then(responseData => {
            console.log(responseData)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err,err.data)
        })
}


getBtn.addEventListener('click',getData)
postBtn.addEventListener('click',sendData)
```

Comment: `.then(errResData => {` you need `.catch(errResData => {` if you want to capture errors...

Comment: could it be a 404 and instead of it returning json like the code is expecting, its returning html? normally the first char in a html document is `<`, hence the error. (though looking at data.phpx, it could be `<?php`)

Comment: I would guess that `response.json()` fails and you never `catch` that one

Comment: See what you have at http://localhost/async/fetch/data.jsonx, I'm pretty sure there's some HTML in there instead of JSON.

Comment: @robo Robok the actual url is localhost/async/fetch/data.json or data.php.  I added an x to both to create a 404 error

Comment: @certain performance response.json() generates a promise.  so I should be at the catch in the get-data() or send-data() functions

Comment: @DCR You *are* catching the error of that promise there. It's just that `response.json()` failed to parse the non-JSON response, so your `then` handler that would've constructed a custom error never ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see if a body is parseable as JSON, you need to call `.json` on the Promise. That will return a Promise that either resolves to the parsed value, or will throw due to the body not being parseable.

If it isn't parseable, `.then`s connected to it won't run;  `return response.json().then` will not work if the body isn't parseable, so the interpreter never gets to `new Error('something went wrong')`.

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.status)
    if(response.status >= 400 || response == null){
        return response.json()
            .then(errResData => {
                const error = new Error('something went wrong')
                error.data = errResData
                throw error;
            })
    }
    return response.json()
```

should be

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.status)
    if(response.status >= 400 || response == null){
        return response.json()
            .catch(errResData => {
                const error = new Error('something went wrong')
                error.data = errResData
                throw error;
            })
    }
    return response.json()
```

if the non-parseable response will always fulfill the condition `response.status >= 400 || response == null`.

The `throw error` inside the `.catch` in the edited code will result in the Promise rejecting, so `getData`'s `.catch` will see the error.

Comment: I follow what you are suggesting but believe you may have overlooked a potential problem.  What happens if we have an error but response.json() returns.  I think we need both a .then and a .catch

Comment: What do you mean, `but response.json() returns`? If, per your question, the error message you want to catch here is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 undefined`, then adding `.catch` instead of `.then` will properly catch the unparseable JSON.

Comment: yes, that's true but only because response.json() didn't work.  suppose the response back was null, throw error would never be invoked cause it's in a catch not a then

Comment: `.json` didn't work only because the response wasn't JSON-parseable. `fetch` can't ever return `null` anyway - it'll always be a `Response` type object. If you want to check that the parsed result isn't null, do that in *another* `.then` after calling `.json` - but that's pretty weird, and should probably be handled by the caller instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch an error from a Promise, you should use `.catch()` instead of `.then()`